# exc_arithmetic error, c++ xcode 4.62

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner of c++. I want know why the exception is thrown at this line:

```
operator double() const
{
    return this->denominator/this->numerator;
}
```

I found `numerator == 0`,but I have given default values in the `ctor`. Why? Please help me.

```
class Rational {
public:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    Rational(int numerator = 2, int denominator = 1)
    {
        numerator = 2;
        denominator = 1;
    };

    operator double() const
    {
        return this->denominator/this->numerator;
    };

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Rational r(1, 2);
    cout << r;
    //   double d = 0.5*r;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code and format your code properly. Furthermore, I don’t understand your question.

Comment: Do you divide `int` by an `int` and expect `double`? Try again, think harder.

Comment: You assign values to the constructor arguments, leaving the member variables uninitialized. If your members have the same identifier, you must prepend this-> when assigning.

Comment: It would be even better to do this in a ctor initializer list.

Comment: Adding to what Frank said, It's better to use an initialization list. You won't need to prefix `this->` if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this line is *very* wrong:

```
Rational(int numerator = 2, int denominator = 1){ numerator = 2; denominator = 1;};
```

The arguments `numerator` and `denominator` are in the stack frame of your ctor thus hiding your class's members `Rational::numerator` and `Rational::denominator` and secondly, you are completely ignoring what the caller actually sends as its arguments (not because you specify the default values, but because you explicitly set `numerator=2; denominator=1`.  This line should actually be:

```
Rational(int numerator = 2, int denominator = 1){ this->numerator = numerator; this->denominator = denominator;};
```

*OR* you could use an initializer list (and overloaded constructors):

```
Rational() : numerator(2), denominator(1) {};
Rational(int numerator, int denominator) : numerator(numerator), denominator(denominator) {};
```

Now, the second problem is that `int/int => int` :: dividing an integer by another integer yields integer division, you need to cast one of your int's to double so that both int's are upconverted to double before calculating the division, like so:

```
operator double() const{ return ((double)this->denominator)/this->numerator;};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Rational(int numerator = 2, int denominator = 1)
{
    numerator = 2;
    denominator = 1;
};
```

I would change this to

```
    Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    this->numerator = numerator;
    this->denominator = denominator;
};
```

I don't know exactly if this is causing your problem, but I think it's contributing to it. Your call to Rational(int,int) will still work fine and add your specified values into the Object you're creating.

The issue with your code, is scope. I believe you were just re-assigning the arguments/parameters instead of actually re-assigning your instance variables, which I'm assuming was your goal.

Comment: The actual exception is probably *divide by zero* caused by failed class initialisation, which you have corrected.

Comment: @trojanfoe exactly - since he was never re-assigning the instance variables, I'm assuming they were somehow set to 0 (even though I thought C++ just gave them "garbage" values at first?) thus causing the divide by zero error. They weren't ever getting re-assigned because he was just changing the arguments' values instead of the instance variables. At least these are my thoughts